# blazor, Difference between define field outside @code directive and inside it

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

[Blazor component defined field inside and out side code directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5EFp.jpg)

what's different between  define field outside @code directive and inside it.

```
@{ int color = 128;} 
for(int i =0; i<250 ;i++) 
{
   color++;
   <span>@color </span>
} 
<h1>@color</h1>

@code{
    int color = 128;
}
```

i noticed that, there are difference when i use these in for..
please explain what happened and why happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is scope and when the variable is initialized.

The stuff in your `code` block is initialized before any of the markup renders, and is available to everything in the component.

The stuff in your markup is local, and exists only in the scope of the markup-- so you can put things like counters or temporary string variables there.

Think of your markup as a funny-looking C# code block, and you'll have the right idea.

Comment: Or consider markup section as one instance method. You can access other instance members from this method, but you can not access variables defined in this method outside of it.

Comment: I wouldn't say "or."  I think that's a better way of putting it. :D

Comment: Thank you guys, your descriptions help me to understand what's going on.